# Simulating gravity between many objects in less than O(n^2) time

Tags: algorithm, simulation

I am writing a simulation with `n` particles that are all "gravitationally" attracted to each other. In order to calculate the forces on each particle, I iterate through a list of the particles. For each particle in the list, I iterate through the same list, calculate the acceleration due to gravity due to each of the other particles, and add each acceleration to the net force on that particle.

While this algorithm works and is more or less accurate, it has O(n^2) execution time. Does a faster algorithm exist?

Comment: maybe something like the *central field approximation* is what you are looking for, although thats more for spherically symmetric systems. complexity would be O(n)

Comment: At some point, you will have to calculate the distance between each pair of particles. Without approximating, it seems like you can't do better than O(n^2).

Comment: Each particle accelerates toward the center of mass of the system, which you can compute straightforwardly in O(*n*) time by taking coordinatewise weighted averages of the particles' positions. But that only gives you the *direction* of acceleration; I'm not sure how to compute the *magnitude*.

Comment: @ruakh Are you certain that each particle accelerates toward the center of mass of the system? I remember learning in one of my physics classes that inside a hollow sphere, gravitational forces cancel out, and there is a net 0 force of gravity despite the fact that there is a clear center of mass. I imagine the principals that make this true would expand to more generalized systems of particles.

Comment: At some distance the influence of the gravitation from far apart particles converges to zero and you can probably just guess the influence as small value. Also when computing the influence to a group of particles that are close together, you can optimize by doing this only for one of them (a leader, the one with the highest influence). The influence of the other particles is more or less the same, you can estimate it. If the system is more or less stable you can also apply some techniques of `route planning`, like a `landmark heuristic` as it can be used in `A-star`.

Comment: @Zabuza How would you determine what is and is not "far apart"? Would it be relative to the current distances in the system. Also, would you be able to direct me to an algorithm for finding clusters for the particle grouping?

Comment: Just some ideas, I have no algorithm or article at hand.

Comment: What is the application? Is it for a game? i.e. is it good enough that it "looks" accurate?

Comment: @samgak No, it is not for a game. It is for modelling a system. It may be enough for it to "look" accurate, but I would like the general behavior to be the same or very similar to the n^2 approach. If the outcome diverges too much, I would be concerned about accumulating errors over time.

Comment: How large is `n`? For a _very__ large system, a self-consistent approximation may work.

Comment: @user58697 In general, I would like `n` to be at least 1000. What is a self-consistent approximation?

Comment: I am afraid, 1000 is not large enough. The approximation works well for objects like gas clouds or start nebulae (that is, billions of objects). The idea is that the field is more or less constant, and changes much lower than individual object moves. There are some references (mostly in a relativistic context, but I am sure they can be simplified for a classical case) in Google Books. Search for "self consistent gravity approximation".

Comment: @KaiSchmidt: I felt pretty certain when I was writing it, but the more I think about it, the less certain I am. :-P

Comment: How large is the geometric space that you are modeling and what sort of spatial resolution are you hoping to achieve? One straightforward method would be to loop through each particle to update a global map of the gravitational potential field / acceleration vector g (the latter probably numerically more accurate), on some grid or other mesh throughout your geometry. Then, in a second loop, for each particle you apply the force at the point at which it is currently located, possibly interpolating between the nearest grid points. The trickiest part would be avoiding self-interaction.

Answer (score 1):

For very high numbers of N it may be faster to approximate n-body gravity by creating a mesh, and then calculating for each point on this mesh the mean gravity exerted by all particles. You could then per particle look at the nearest few mesh points and approximate the total gravitational force on the particle from those. However, this would only be faster if the total points on the mesh is smaller than the number of particles.

Some other approaches are the Barnes–Hut simulation and the fast multipole method, but these will accumulate errors over time.

However, depending on the length of your simulation, you will start to build up errors anyway, since (nearly) all non-integral numbers in a computer are approximations.

Comment: One would need to be careful to avoid self-interaction - each particle would contribute greatly to the nearby gravitational field, but this needs to be neglected when computing the force on the particle due to the field.

Comment: @jwimberley : true. However, since each's particles contribution to the gravitational mesh is additive, it's quite simple to substract the particle's own gravitational influence before doing so.

Comment: I agree; I'd just like to note that depending on the mesh size, the particle's own gravitation influence might dominate, and the computation would be "(small number + big number) - big number" and might suffer from imprecision.